# VS Code does not provide autocomplete for some HTML attributes in django templates

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

When I'm programming with django, some HTML attributes do not have autocomplete in VS Code. For example, this is the case with the `enctype` attribute in a `from` tag.

In file settings.json I have written:

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html",
```

But it helps only partly. All tags have autocomplete, but the attributes of some don't have autocomplete anyway.

After deactivating `django - html`, autocomplete starts working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration

```json
      "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html",
        "python": "html",
        "html": "html",
      }
```

Or use [custom code snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets) or ***GitHub Copilot*** etc.

some additional extensions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_html-extensions